# How can this for-loop with range be explained

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Can someone please help me how to understand this code:

```
j = 0
for i in range(1, 8, 2):
    j += i
    print (j)
```

The output is: 1 4 9 16

But I just cannot understand why. I get the concept of for-loops and range. But the involvement of the variable and the += operand makes me confused. Can someone explain this step by step, so that I can understand why the output is what it is?

Comment: `j += i` is just the same thing as `j = j + i`.

Comment: What about `+=` confuses you? Do you know what that operator does?

Comment: Try `print(list(range(1, 8, 2))`, and see what values that produces. Do you understand what `range()` does?

Comment: What I don't understand is how the value of j can get to 1,4,9,16 in the iterations. I can't get it to ad up with the stop-value in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First iteration, j is 0, i is 1. j is set to 0+1 == 1.

Second interation, j is 1, i is 3. j is set to 1+3 == 4.

Third iteration, j is 4, i is 5. j is set to 4+5 == 9.

Fourth iteration, j is 9, i is 7. j is set to 9+7 == 16.

Comment: This makes sense now, since j obviously keeps its value from previous iterations. Thanks a lot, really appreciate it!